# Sleeping on Stones

Tags: minhag, sleep, tisha-bav

Where does the Minhag come from that we should sleep uncomfortably on Tisha B'Av?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Chasam Sofer** in **Toras Moshe**(Bereishis 28:11 ) says the night Yackov slept on stones was *Tisha B'Av* also brought by the **Ramah**(555:2),  and hence we understand the deeper meaning of the dream of malachim going up and down. Each rung repesented a year in golus until the first Geulah and going up again the rungs represented the years of the second golus until the third time and he did not see it come down again, that is our golus. Now it makes sense as it was the actual night the two Churbanos happened.

Comment: Not sure about the fact that the night Yaakov slept there it was Tisha Be'av. Rama only brings down (in name of Mordechai, based on Sifrei 352) that Yaakov's statement "How awesome is this place?" was in reaction to the churban being revealed to him. See: http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%94 This is a bit out of order since Yaakov put the stone under his head, then dreamed and presumably that's when he received prophecy of the churban. But we're putting the stone under ou